# How to remove style tags from divs with certain class

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

How can I (with PHP) remove the style attributes from DIVS having a certain class?
Because of an 'Drag&Drop' process some DIV elements get polluted with unnecessary styles which can lead to problems later on.

I know I can remove the style attributes with JavaScript after a 'Drag&Drop' process, but I only remove them when to HTML is being processed by the server (For sending the HTML as an e-mail).

Comment: check this out http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: @Pēteris No, don't. Regex is not the way to parse anything but the very simplest HTML structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a particularly difficult problem, so far as I can tell.  You need to load the HTML into a DOMDocument structure, then use a simple XPath attribute selector to find the relevant elements and [`DOMElement::removeAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.removeattribute.php) to remove the style attribute.  Your code might look like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($dirtyHtml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$divs = $xpath->query('//div[@class="someclass"]');

foreach ($divs as $div) {
    $div->removeAttribute('style');
}

$cleanHtml = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Having a "duuhh" moment when seeing the solution ;)