# Remove class/style/junk from within specified html tags

Tags: php, regex

Using PHP and Regex, how can I strip all unwanted style, class or other junk from inside a tag?

EG:

```
<span class="blah" style="blah" any other junk >...</span>
```

would be cleaned to this: `<span>...</span>`.

I'm trying to put together a function like so:

```
function cleanTag($html, $tagType='div'){
  $html = // regex to clean out all tags of $tagType in $html
  return $html;
}
```

I'd like it to work on any tag type I set as `$tagType`.

Needs to be in PHP - I'm doing it server side. Thanks.

Comment: Additional possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179206 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104962 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371527. And also check the related section for possible more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to target specific tags you will need to dynamically adjust the regular expression, make sure to use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote) to avoid allowing regex matching in the `$tagType` parameter.

The following function will work with less strict tag restrictions than the previous answer, e.g. try the test after the function code.

```
function cleanTag($html, $tagType = 'div') {
    if ($tagType) {
        // match specific tag
        $tagType = preg_quote($tagType);
    } else {
        // match all tags
        $tagType = '[\w\d]+';
    }

    return preg_replace("/<\s*($tagType).*?>/si", '<$1>', $html);
}
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9q7-bnr

Textual explanation:

- `/`
- `<` Match an open bracket
- `\s*` Match zero or more space characters (space, tab, newline)
- `([\w\d]+)`/`($tagType)` Capture the alphanumeric/explicit tag name
- `.*?>` Match zero or more characters until a close tag is found
- `/si` Dot character matches new lines and insensitive comparison

The string replaces the entire match with new tags which contain the captured tag `$1`